# Is brute force conditional probability a good algorithm product recommendations?

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, recommender-system

I'm creating a recommendations system for an e-commerce web application. I need an algorithm.

I've come across conditional probability, which might be what I need. I heard very little about recommendations algorithms built with conditional probability, and I need to hear thoughts if it's any good.

This is how the algorithm I was thinking of will go:

- For every product visited by a customer, let X be the event where customer purchases this product
- For every other product in the system, let Y be the event where the customer purchases that other product.
- The probability of a customer purchasing a product is defined by the amount of times the product has appeared in orders, over the amount of total orders.

I would calculate P(Y | X), and then sort by highest probability, then take the top.

Is this a good algorithm? Does this technically count as machine learning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this would not work well.

There will probably be some products that are popular among everyone and these will have a high value for $P(Y|X)$ for all $X$. What you actually want to show is cases where $P(Y|X)$ has a large increase relative to $P(Y)$.

There are other things that can go wrong with the "brute-force" strategy too. For example, you often can't get good estimates for $P(Y|X)$ without applying some smoothing.